# netstat -r output, internet vs internet6, different gateway formats

Tags: networking, macos, routing, ipv6, netstat

What's the difference between internet and internet6 routes? I'm assuming internet6 stands for IPv6?

```
netstat -r
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            10.11.254.254      UGSc           61        0     en0
10.11/16           link#4             UCS            32        0     en0
e1r1p3.42.fr       10:dd:b1:a4:2f:33  UHLWI           0        0     en0    696
e1r1p8.42.fr       10:dd:b1:c1:76:9b  UHLWI           0        0     en0    345
e1r1p9.42.fr       10:dd:b1:a2:7f:3a  UHLWI           0        0     en0   1129
e1r1p12.42.fr      10:dd:b1:be:73:6f  UHLWI           0        0     en0   1066
e1r2p4.42.fr       10:dd:b1:b8:f1:c0  UHLWI           0        0     en0    702
e1r2p19.42.fr      10:dd:b1:c1:63:19  UHLWI           0        0     en0   1152
e1r3p5.42.fr       10:dd:b1:a4:2d:b5  UHLWI           0        0     en0    547
e1r3p17.42.fr      10:dd:b1:c1:61:ca  UHLWI           0        0     en0    874
e1r3p19.42.fr      10:dd:b1:c1:69:b1  UHLWI           0        0     en0    860
.......

Internet6:
Destination        Gateway            Flags         Netif Expire
default            fe80::%utun0       UGcI          utun0
localhost          localhost          UHL             lo0
fe80::%lo0         fe80::1%lo0        UcI             lo0
fe80::1%lo0        link#1             UHLI            lo0
fe80::%en0         link#4             UCI             en0
e1r10p17.local     10:dd:b1:c1:6f:d3  UHLI            lo0
fe80::%awdl0       link#10            UCI           awdl0
e1r10p17.local     fe:28:c6:17:d6:fc  UHLI            lo0
..............
```

Why are the gateways referring to interfaces in the Internet6 section and  in the Internet section they are basically Mac Addresses, and regular IP's with the exception of `link#4`? And how do I break down the gateways like 'fe80::%utun0', what dos this mean?

Comment: There isn’t one MAC address in this entire output though...?

Comment: My bad. I edited and included some more output

Comment: They're probably ARP and NDP cache entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the question is about IPv6.

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags         Netif Expire
default            fe80::%utun0       UGcI          utun0
localhost          localhost          UHL             lo0
fe80::%lo0         fe80::1%lo0        UcI             lo0
fe80::1%lo0        link#1             UHLI            lo0
fe80::%en0         link#4             UCI             en0
e1r10p17.local     10:dd:b1:c1:6f:d3  UHLI            lo0
fe80::%awdl0       link#10            UCI           awdl0
e1r10p17.local     fe:28:c6:17:d6:fc  UHLI            lo0
```

All the fe80-addresses are link-local adresses.In other words: these are addresses that belong to specific interfaces and are valid only on the directly connected network. These addresses will not be routed through your network. For each interface, you will have such an fe80:: network.

So, from the netstat output, I get the impression you're on a MAC (utun), you are running some sort of virtual-machine setup and you have  the following interfaces:

- lo0, the loopback interface
- en0, an ethernet interface
- a sort of tunnel, utun, which is the default gateway
- An apple wireless direct link

All these devices have an fe80:: address; the % means that it is the fe80::n network for that interface.

IPv6 addresses leave out the zeroes (well, not all, but you should consult some IPv6 documentation on that) So, fe80:: is really fe80:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000.

The `link#<number>` indicate devices or networks that are reachable at the link-layer. That means more or less that they are directly connected (connected in the broader sense; WiFi can be connected too). So your link#1 is the network connected to your loopback, link#4 is the network connected to your ethernet en0 and link#10 is the network connected to your wireless.

Comment: Thank you! Good explanation. Now, what about the link#number addresses? I didn't quite get what they are and what they are doing. If you could delve into thata bit it would be great. Thanks again

Comment: added the explanation.